# How do i find the "SUM()" in my Shopping Cart

Tags: meteor-blaze

I’m trying to make an e-shop: ( this is a simplified example )

I have a product collection:

Product = new Mongo. Collection(“product”);
title - price - image

in my shopTemplate i run #each products with a quantity input and a “Buy” button
This will be inserted in a selectedProducts collection:

SelectedProducts = new Mongo.Collection(“selectedProduct”);
image - tittle - price - quantity - subtotal

in my shoppingcartTemplate i run #each selectedProducts with “+” and “-” buttons for the
quantity and an update button( update subtotal accor. to quantity changes)and of course an delete btn.

when i render this in my shopping cart, it will look like this

image - title - price -"+" quantity “-” - subtotal - “update” - “delete”

image - title - price -"+" quantity “-” - subtotal - “update”- “delete”

image - title - price -"+" quantity “-” - subtotal - “update”- “delete”

image - title - price -"+" quantity “-” - subtotal - “update”- “delete”

image - title - price -"+" quantity “-” - subtotal - “update”- “delete”

image - title - price -"+" quantity “-” - subtotal - “update”- “delete”

etc.
etc.

### etc.

### ----

The shoppingCart is dynamically rendered, and all corresponding elements have the same id!

Now my question is: **How do I get the sum() of the subtotals**

I other words I need a totalBuy.value to use in my order collection for tax calculations etc.

Comment: You can use jQuery to detect the values within each field and then fire off a method that saves the current selected products value for the current session. Just be careful not to bloat the collection.

Comment: Thanks Harry. Could you please make the answer a little bit more detailed

Comment: yeah, sure thing. https://gist.github.com/harryadelb/4a406afc52b873cd60ea3b0feecd05d0

Comment: Keep in mind, you didn't really provide any of your code so I was working off of my imagination.